# Java RMI on the web

Tags: java, rmi, java-web-start

I have to send data ( user details to be more specific) from one machine to a server.. where it could be stored in the database.. hence, i created a RMI application that sends the user details object from a client to the server. But, i did this on the localhost itself.. running two java processes(the client and the server) together on the same machine... 
Now, i want to extend the application such that it could work on any two machines connected to the internet...
Please Help

Comment: http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csneal/InternetComputing/Tunnelling.html could be your starting point

Comment: 1) Work through the [RMI tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html). 2) Work through the [Java Web Start tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/). 3) Drop back by when you have a more specific question.

Comment: Actually my real problem is.. how would my client know my server's address.. it is a dynamic IP right...

Comment: @Abhay:How is this question related to RMI?Anyway...That is why you use `FQDN`.So that the IP can change anytime

Answer (score 0):

Too broad question.
Register in the rmi registry using an `IP` or `fqdn` (and the port) that is accessible by the clients.
E.g. `Object o2 = Naming.lookup("rmi://my.site.com:2099/myoperation");`

You do realize though that your clients can **only** be Java applications?

Comment: Yeah I do, I actually feel quite lame asking this question.. But i have no idea how to put my classes on a web-server.. I just want a client server communication (sending and receiving objects) between some remote machines...

Comment: Sorry but what is your question exactly?If you really need help you should update the OP with as much information you can along with exactly what is your problem.Make sure that your post asks exactly 1 clear question

Comment: @Abhay:I read your update.You have already code in place and tested it as I read.So using an `FQDN` is not an answer for you?